# зацикленная музыка в игре

Tags: python, разработка-игр, аудио, pygame

при проигрыше музыка повторяется миллион раз помогите

```
введите сюда код
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([900,750])
flag = True
print(pygame.font.get_fonts())
pic = pygame.image.load("CrazySmile.bmp")
picx =0
picy = 0
BLACK = (0,0,0)
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
speedx =5
speedy =5
WHITE = (255,255,255)
paddulew=200
padduleh=30
padduley=700
paddulex=300
picw=100
pich=100
point= 0
lives=3
font = pygame.font.SysFont("microsoftyaheitruetypemicrosoftyaheiuibold",24)
pop = pygame.mixer.Sound("pop.wav")
gameover=pygame.mixer.Sound("gameover.wav")

while flag:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            flag = False
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_F1:
                point=0
                lives=5
                picx=0
                picy=0
                speedx=5
                speedy=5
    picx+=speedx
    picy+=speedy
    if picx<=0 or picx+pic.get_width()>= 900:
        speedx=-int(speedx*1.1)
    if picy <=0:
        speedy=-speedy
    if picy>=650:
        lives-=1
        speedy=-speedy
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    paddulex=pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    paddulex-=paddulew//2
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(paddulex,padduley,paddulew,padduleh))
    if picy+pich>=padduley and picy+pich<=padduley+padduleh and speedy>0:
        if picx+picw/2>=paddulex and picx +picw/2<=paddulex+paddulew:
            point+=1
            pop.play()
            speedy=-speedy
    string ="  Жизни:"+str(lives)+" очки:"+str(point)
    if lives<1:
        speedx=speedy=0
        string="Игра окончена.Вы набрали очков: "+str(point)
        string+=" f1=продолжение(нажмите)"
        gameover.play()
        
    text=font.render(string,True,WHITE)
    rec=text.get_rect()
    rec.y=10
    screen.blit(text,rec)
    rec.centerx=screen.get_rect().centerx
    screen.blit(pic,(picx,picy))
    pygame.display.update()
    timer.tick(90)    
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно как-нибудь так. Заведите переменную `gameoverstate = False` и потом проверяйте её. Только не забудьте по `F1` её тоже сбрасывать, как и остальное состояние. Таким образом этот блок кода, где играет финальная музыка, будет выполняться только один раз, когда кончатся жизни:

```
    if lives<1 and not gameoverstate:
        speedx=speedy=0
        string="Игра окончена.Вы набрали очков: "+str(point)
        string+=" f1=продолжение(нажмите)"
        gameover.play()
        gameoverstate = True
```